# php regex find string between line start and empty line without lines that starts with any html tags

Tags: php, regex

hello i have to get any lines without html tags into this format

```
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

e.g.

```
hello world

<h2>lol</h2>

lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet

consetetur
```

should parsed to

```
<p>hello world</p>

<h2>lol</h2>

<p>lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet</p>

<p>consetetur</p>
```

i tried this with the php function preg_replace();

does someone can help?

P.S. I'll trie to get this syntax into html

```
# header 1 // <h1>header 1</h1>
## header 2 // <h2>header 2</h2>
```

and all lines without header should parse into

... my headers will be parsed but the paragraphs not

Comment: Remember the obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :)

Comment: /^[^(<)(.+)(>)](.*)(^[\r?\n?]$)/m replaced with <p>\1</p> this is the regex i tried in different variants

Comment: The input already contains HTML tags, so your question is a bit imprecise on what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit verbose, but it should be solid.  It uses `DOMDocument` rather than regex:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<root>' . $yourContent .'</root>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('/root/text()');

function wrapnode ($node) {
    global $dom;

    $p = $dom->createElement('p');
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($p, $node);
    $p->appendChild($node);
}

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        $node->nodeValue = trim($node->nodeValue);

        while ($location = strpos($node->nodeValue, "\n\n")) {
            $newnode = $node->splitText($location);
            wrapnode($node);

            $node = $newnode;
            $node->nodeValue = trim($node->nodeValue);
        }

        wrapnode($node);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: `$node->nodeValue = trim($node->nodeValue);` will take care that `"\n\n"` is never found at the end of it so renders most of the code useless - if I have spotted that right.

Comment: @hakre Yes, the `\n\n` are removed by this code. They are ignored in rendered HTML anyway. This code breaks on `\n\n` in the *middle* of strings.

Comment: but doesn't that mean that simple lines of text will be converted into paragraphs as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "simple lines of text"?

Comment: Those w/o "\n" at the beginning or end. (for the example data given by the OP it works.)

Comment: @hakre Could you provide some data where it wouldn't work? I'm afraid I don't understand your point.

Comment: sure, take this and check the output: `$yourContent = "hello world\n\n<h2>lol</h2>test";`. Will wrap test into p while test has not line breaks surrounding. Typically I would says double line break = p.

Comment: @hakre *shrug* That seems like a good thing to me. All unwrapped text is wrapped in `p` elements. I may have misinterpreted the question, but it is fairly vague.

Comment: I think the question is not precise, so nobody could really say. I'll run a test converting the HTML 2 into domdocument (my suggestion below) to see how it performs.

Comment: Works, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as valid HTML 2.0 is concerned**, [`<p>` does not need to be a pair](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.1). So to create HTML of the input HTML with additional paragraphs per a double line break, it's very simple:

```
$html = str_replace("\n\n", '<p>', $html);
```

Keep in mind that this solution is very specific to the input and the output, so it might solve part of the scenario in your question only. However I could not get enough information from your question to give a better answer.

**As far as HTML 4.0.1 is concerned**, this can be created with ease out of it:

```
$html = str_replace("\n\n", "<p>", $yourContent);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

DomDocument can convert the HTML 2 into HTML 4.0.1 and will add all needed HTML elements like doctype, html and body. only the head and title is missing.

Comment: Supported by every browser out there. Works like a charm. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works in java:

```
input.replaceAll("(?<=\\n\\n)(?=\\w)", "<p>").replaceAll("(?<=\\w)(?=\\n\\n)", "</p>");
```

However it's a bit brittle: It does two replacements that might not be connected.